# MVC Simple Membership Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, simplemembership, user-roles

I must have missed this somewhere (or slept through the class)... the standard ASP security tool for managing users and roles seems to be absent when using the new simple security version.  That is, the original is there and working, just points to traditional ASP security... NOT to the new "simple" system.

In my project I can log in, I can look at the webpages_ tables but can find no method of accessing them in my project... I would be happy to manage roles and get the USERID and maybe ROLEID so I could tie the user to other functions in my project.

I've looked through hundreds of posts and articles... normally I find I am missing some minor config entry or something but this time I am a little more stuck.

Advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I developed an alternative to the Website Administration Tool. info: http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/08/aspnet-mvc-4-simplemembershipprovider_20.html Code: https://github.com/StoneFinch/SmpMaintenance

Answer (score 1):

SimpleMembership does not work with the Web Site Administration Tool (WSAT).  There is a good [overview of SimpleMembership in this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx).  Here is a quote from it.

> WSAT is built to work with ASP.NET Membership, and is not compatible with Simple Membership. There are two main options there:
>
> 1. Use the WebSecurity and OAuthWebSecurity API to manage the users and
>      roles.
> 2. Create a web admin using the above APIs.
> 3. Since SimpleMembership
>      runs on top of your database, you can update your users as you would
>      any other data - via EF or even in direct database edits (in
>      development, of course)

I would also add that you can seed some of this information at application start-up, such as what roles are available, as [shown in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Comment: Those are some better links then I have been finding.  Thanks.

Comment: Any custom solutions to address this functionality ? Or we have to develop our own solution. i.e make crud for users and role and assign roles to users, have listing of users and roles and roles having permissions to view/modify pages of website.

Comment: I am not aware of any custom solutions and did not see any when you google for it.  The problem is SimpleMembership give you a fair amount of flexibility in customizing how you implement membership that any admin tool would have to be customized to work with it.  So you just about have to create your own solution.